# Can't add elevation and radius to my cardview

Tags: android, cardview, radius, elevation

This is my UI Design:
[UI Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MYew.png)

And this is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:rowCount="2"
            android:columnCount="2"
            >

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="20dp" <--- :"(
                app:cardElevation="20dp" <--- :"(
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_square">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/dashPlaceholder"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:textSize="8pt"
                        android:text="@string/findBengkel"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            ...


        </GridLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

and this is the result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdhS7.png)

Comment: You can use materialCardView instead of androidx.cardview.widget.CardView . implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1". Just change your CardView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/card_view_DailyTicket"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_directions_car_24" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Hourly Tickets"
                            android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Try this. from my current project. its piece of cake. runs well. hope that will help**

Comment: Corner radius does work, but relevation doesn't work, but thanks for tried to help me :)

Comment: Best Of Luck Brother

Comment: @AbdulSalam Try this same answer and set the elevation to 4dp.

Comment: The answer sets elevation to 0, you change it to whatever you want. Set a background AND an elevation to the card

Answer (score 0):

```
app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
app:cardElevation="0dp"
```

and also use **backgroundTint** with any color to confirm if its working or not. i edited your Card and it Worked!

**and most importantly manage your grid layout width and height nicely either you would get difficulties.**

Comment: i tried to change it to: app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
app:cardElevation="0dp"

Comment: @AbdulSalam look for my another answer. hope that would help